# Older XTR cranks - replace or adapt?

Tags: shimano, crankset

I've been using Shimano XTR cranks since my bike was assembled in 2002 (fc-m952?). I've replaced the rings a few times in the past (though not in several years) but it appears that these cranks were crafted in such a way as to preclude the use of off-the-shelf rings. As a result it seems to be rather difficult / impossible to find replacements anymore.

I'm in need of new rings again so it seems I have two choices:

1. Replace the whole set
2. Adapt using something like [this](http://www.mtbtandems.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=62_84&product_id=78) - and replace with 'standard' rings

I don't know enough about bike parts and availability to make a clear decision.

Suggestions?

---

EDIT:

I should note that the shifters are also XTR of the same era so any replacement rings would need to be compatible

Comment: I'd be tempted to go with the option that allows me to think about this once, get the job done, then forget about it. Do both of your approaches offer that? I mean, next time you change the rings, you don't want to have to ask this question again, do you? Also, does cost come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shifters+front derailleur don't care about the type of chain rings you're using (just that they're sized appropriately and you're running a double/triple as you were before).

On the one hand, the adapter you linked is about 75 dollars + the cost of regular rings (which should work fine). On the other hand, replacing the crankset means a new bottom bracket (octalink v1 isn't exactly popular anymore,but its not hard to find replacement octalink v1 bottom brackets) and a new crankset.

I'd probably personally opt for the new crankset and BB, since I don't know about the reliability of these adapters and the price difference is pretty small (maybe 15 dollars). Plus, then, you don't risk someone putting a Octalink v2 BB on there some point and then ruining the crank.

Comment: From what I've found a new XTR crank will run me > $400. If the shifters don't  care then I'll probably try the adapter. If that doesn't work then I'll have to replace everything anyway...

Comment: You don't have to replace the crank with a new XTR crank -- a modern Deore crank is around 70 dollars and it's likely as good as a ~15 year old XTR crank.

Comment: Double plus 1 for the above answer. You should be able to find a 9spd  XT crank with BB for about $150. External bearing make for a lighter crank than even XTR octalink versions. http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/shimano-xt-m770-triple-chainset/rp-prod20679 IMHO, unless you've either got deep pockets or are racing at a very high level XTR is not worth the extra cash over XT. Even plain Deore is perfectly servicable these days.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to change the crank. A 2015 Deore or a SLX crank are not only extremely good value for money but they also carry a lot of modern technologies (search the net for reviews, everybody loves them) comparing with your old 2002 product.

A modern 2015 Deore (cheapest, entry level) works much better than a 2002 XTR because 13 years of development really make a big difference.

Good luck and happy riding.

Comment: What sorts of improvements would one look for?

Comment: Hollow cranks and spindle, external bearings, redesigned cogs with support gears, 3D composite chain rings, overall smarter construction with modern materials. 13 years is a big gap in any product.

Comment: Yes this - Shimano tech trickles down from current XTR over a few  years to the lower end groupsets.